# save coordinates to firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, coordinates

please help me to get the coordinates of specific location and send it to firebase. most of the guides are now old because of the changes in flutter and they doesn't work anymore.

I tried using some packages like `glocater` and `geoflutterfire` but nothing work because of the changes

Comment: Have you checked this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator it seems this has a detailed desc

Comment: You can go through with this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/background_geolocation_firebase which is helpful for the case.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that you need to take

1. Create the [geolocator][1] plugin into your project

```dart
flutter pub add geolocator
```

2. Do a clean on your project just to be sure

```sh
flutter clean
```

3. Do a pub get to get your dependencies

```
flutter pub get
```

4. Grab the user's current location as mentioned in the geolocator's wiki pages

```dart
Position? position = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
```

5. Grab the `position`'s latitude and longitude properties of type double and send those to your Firebase database.

Using
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: sorry i meant a specific location not the user location, can i do that with this plugin?